# Store value in javascript variable

Tags: javascript

I want to create a javascript variable called `myVal` and store 21 inside it upon `onclick`. 21 may any number or string.

```
<a href="#" onclick="store(21)">Store</a>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: FYI, you're going to get lots of downvotes for posting such a simple question. This shows no attempt to learn the basics of the language.

Answer (score 0):

Just assign the variable in the function.

```js
var myVal;

function store(val) {
  myVal = val;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="store(21)">Store 21</a>
<a href="#" onclick="store(50)">Store 50</a>
<br>
<button onclick="alert(myVal)">Show myVal</button>
```